# Java:Methods like ord PHP in Java

Tags: java, php

I want to edit a php's code which used ord methods, the php's code follow:

```
$fh=fopen("../ip.data","r");
fseek($fh,327680);
$country_id=ord(fread($fh,1));  //return 137
```

I try to write code in java :

```
FileReader ip=new FileReader("ip.data");
int i = 0;
int str;
while((str=ip.read()) != -1){
   if(i==327681){
      System.out.println(str);  //return 0
      break;
   }
i++;
}
```

But the two are not equal.
I know `ord('a')==97` in PHP, `(int)'a'==97` in Java.
The ip.data download [here](https://github.com/qlcoder-oreo/taobaoip/blob/master/ip.data).

Comment: Please post and example `ip.data` file and what differences you have in java and in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) assumes the system's default charset for the input file, which *might* be utf-8 e.g.* In that case up to four bytes would be read to "form up" the single *character* you get from FileReader.read().
So maybe (just guesswork at this point though) that's the problem. Your php code doesn't assume any encoding, it just reads an (8bit) byte and its equivalent in java would be e.g.

```
fis = new  FileInputStream("ip.data");
country_id = fis.read(); // FileInputStream.read() is reading a byte, not a character
```

---

*) To test that assumption try

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("ip.data")
System.out.println( fr.getEncoding() );
```

What does it print?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
String str = "t";
byte b = str.getBytes()[0];
int ascii = (int) b;
```

Maybe you have to use char.